# asp.net c# - Check for certain string conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

I'm trying to check for certain conditions in a string. For example these strings:

```
House of Love
Amy Grant House of Love [Remastered]
Amy Grant House of Love [Remastered](new)
Amy Grant - House of Love [Rmstr]
```

What would be a good method to check for special conditons, like looking for what is between brackets, what is between parentheses, what is separated between a hyphen.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void AnalyzeText(string text)
        {
            string[] commonChars = new string[] { "[", "]" };
            string[] commonTags = new string[] {"remastered", "new", "used", "remaster" };
            string[] commonCats = new string[] { "cd", "dvd" };

            int index = Array.IndexOf(commonChars, text);

         
            
        }
```

But I'm wondering what a good method would be to do this. What I'm working towards is having it compare multiple strings to find the best suited title for an item.

Comment: It sounds like you need help developing an algorithm. That's not really a good question for StackOverflow. I think you should post this on Software Engineering instead.  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe have a look at regular expressions